# How can I combine two rows of a dataframe into one?

Tags: r

Basically, I have a simple two column dataframe, one with degrees of a circle in 10° intervals, and the other with the frequencies of those degrees in a different dataframe.

In the degrees column there is a row for 0° and a row for 360°, and since those mean the same thing (in the context of wind direction) I'd like to combine the two rows into a single 0° row. E.g. from:

```
degree   freq 
0        1446
10       7652
20       2655
...
360      5417
```

To this

```
degree   freq 
0        6863
10       7652
20       2655
...
```

I'm sure this a very simple thing to do but I've spent 3 hours trying to figure it out and have gotten nowhere >.>

Comment: one of the easiest solutions in base R is `aggregate(freq~ degree %% 360, df1, sum)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to change the value of 360 to 0 and do a group by 'degree' and get the `sum` of 'freq'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(degree = replace(degree, degree == 360, 0)) %>%
     summarise(freq = sum(freq))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  degree  freq
#*  <dbl> <int>
#1      0  6863
#2     10  7652
#3     20  2655
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(freq ~ degree, transform(df1, 
      degree =  replace(degree, degree == 360, 0)), sum)
```

Or as @Onyambu commented

```
aggregate(freq~ degree %% 360,df1,sum)
```

NOTE: It is a generalized version where multiple elements with 360 can be changed to 0 and then do a group by sum

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(degree = c(0L, 10L, 20L, 360L), freq = c(1446L, 
7652L, 2655L, 5417L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: also `aggregate(freq~ degree %% 360,df1,sum)` would suffice

Comment: @Onyambu that is a much better option.  YOu could post as a solution thanks

Comment: You already have `aggregate` as an option. There is really no much difference

Comment: Thank you both! Used @Onyambu 's line and it worked like a dream :)

Answer (score 1):

If I read you question correctly, your df has only one row with `360`. So, the following may be an option too.

```r
# Add the two rows
df$freq[df$degree == 0] <- 
    df$freq[df$degree == 0] + df$freq[df$degree == 360]

# Delete row
df <- df[ !df$degree==360,]
```